# UPDATE one table based on values in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I have two tables, Table 1 has three fields (a1,a2,a3) and table 2 has three fields (b1,b2,b3) I want to update table one base on table two when a1=b1 . This is essay in Microsoft access but I want t to do it in Microsoft Access project Sql server 2005 as a back end.

```
UPDATE  t1
SET  a1 = t2.b1, a2 = t2.b2, a3 = t2.b3
where a1=b1
```

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN` the tables.  Then you won't need to `SET t1.a1=t2.b1` because those are already equal based on the join condition.  So just `SET` the other two field values ...

```
UPDATE t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.a1=t2.b1
SET t1.a2 = t2.b2, t1.a3 = t2.b3
```

Note this suggestion is Access SQL and should work from MS Access regardless of whether `t1` and `t2` are native Access tables, links to SQL Server tables, or a mix of both types.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET a1 = t2.b1, a2 = t2.b2, a3 = t2.b3
FROM t1
   INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.a1 = t2.b1
```

Comment: create PROCEDURE [dbo].[t122]
 
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE t1
SET a2 = t2.b2, a3 = t2.b3,a1 = t2.b1
FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.a1=t2.b1
WHERE a1 = t2.b1
END